# How to show errors when saving multiple things at once?

Tags: user-expectation, error-message

I have this situation. I have list of data and user can choose one button. After pressing that button dialog is shown to user , with yes and no button. On sucessfull operation element in list disappear and user gets grren notification in right upper corner "Saved successfully", or on failure "Failed because...". 
Everything is fine with that scenario. I like it.
Here is the problem.
I needed to make checkbox near to each element in list, where user can check one or more items in list. Selecting one element triggers visibility of one button (save all) where user can save for example 5 items in once.
Chances are that 3 of those items will be saved corretly but 2 will not. How to shows relevant errors for those items. 
I can't show them as notifications in upper right corner because what when user selects 10 items, and 10 of them fails. Notifications also dissaper automatically after 5 seconds. They will take entire screen from top to bottom and user will not have enaught time to read them. User will notice that few items were not "saved" bacause they remain in list but I'm trying to find the way for showing notifications for t

Comment: It might be helpful if you could show a wireframe or screenshot of what you're working with. It sounds like the "toast" style notifications you're using aren't really suitable for this situation, and inline error messages next to the item in the list is the way to go.

Comment: Yes I thought about inline messages, I can upload images tomorrow but it is really that simple.basic table  with items and checkboxes next to item which enables to save more tham one item at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have a table with a list of items. Assuming this is what you have, is it possible to show the invalid items like this?

[image: Notifying the user of multiple invalid items]

Answer (score 0):

I am working on a similar situation for a B2B financial app. User can import a number of files. The system validates and can reject some and accept others. But the user may want to correct some of the entries and try again, so she needs to know which ones were rejected.

Here's how we handled it:

- User imports a file with 100 records and all are valid. She gets a
  green success message.
- User imports a file with 100 records and all are invalid. She gets a
  red failure message.
- User imports a file with 50 valid and 50 invalid records. The valid
  records are imported, and she gets a yellow message saying "Some of the
  records could not be imported. Download a CSV file of the records we could not import." There's a hyperlink that immediately downloads and the resulting CSV has a reason for rejection for each of the records. The user can make corrections when convenient and import the corrected records.

Answer (score 0):

You can show a separate screen where you will be showing unsaved or saved items (any of them) though I will recommend to show unsaved items. If in each step something is not saved, it will appear there with some small indication(without individual errors)., list of unsaved items will be available for the user and while clicking on an item, again the submission process for unsaved items will be initiated. You can also have a special option to process all the unsaved items at once.

If it's a web-based application, i would suggest to use something similar to cookies to store those entries temporarily (until they are reflected on the server).